# How was Lucifer created?

Tags: creation, satan

Was Lucifer created by God or was he already there in the beginning like God? I don't think the Bible really explains any of this.

Comment: Hi! It's important to be aware that different denominations have different viewpoints on this question, and this website is oriented to talk about the beliefs of different denominations. Before I can vote this up, I need to see some specificity on the question: please [edit] it to point to a specific denomination or group of denominations. Also: I have a feeling this has been answered here before. Take a  search through it and see if you find anything that helps you.

Comment: That's true, there is almost nothing about Lucifer in the Bible.

Comment: I'm not aware of any denominations which think Satan is a self-existing eternal being, so I don't think denominational scoping is needed.

Comment: @curiousdannii I think we should probably differentiate between the very different LDS understanding of Satan. Jehovah's witnesses also seem to believe in a relatively strong Satan so I'm not sure if their version of his creation is different.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This question is off-topic and does not fit into one of the [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409) Specifically, it is what we call a Truth question, which means you need to tell us who's opinion you want (Catholic, John Calivin, etc.) If possible, [edit] this question so that it better fits into one of those question types.

Comment: Lucifer not exist anywhere in the bible I read (not one single verse) - just saying. Please define who Lucifer is to you and maybe consider removing the name all together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through modern revelation in the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints, we know that Satan, also called the adversary or the devil, is the enemy of all righteousness and of those who seek to follow God. He is a spirit son of God who was once an angel “in authority in the presence of God”.

> "And this we saw also, and bear record, that an angel of God who was in
>   authority in the presence of God, who rebelled against the Only
>   Begotten Son whom the Father loved and who was in the bosom of the
>   Father, was thrust down from the presence of God and the Son," ([D&C 76:25;](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/76.25?lang=eng#24) see also [Isaiah 14:12;](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/isa/14.12?lang=eng#11) [D&C 76:26–27](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/76.26-27?lang=eng#25))

But in the premortal Council in Heaven, Lucifer, as Satan was then called, rebelled against God. Since that time, he has sought to destroy the children of God on the earth and to make them miserable.

Prior to his rebellion, Lucifer was not unlike the other angels in heaven, he would have been created as they were:

> "For by him were all things created, that are in heaven, and that are
>   in earth, visible and invisible, whether they be thrones, or
>   dominions, or principalities, or powers: all things were created by
>   him, and for him:" *[(1 Colossians 1:16)](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/col/1.16?lang=eng#15)*

Comment: Your answer is a good answer for "who created.." it is not a good answer for "How..."

Answer (score 2):

In the words of Jesus:

> Mark 12:24  And Jesus answering said unto them, Do ye not therefore err, because ye know not the scriptures, neither the power of God?

All Scripture is quoted from the King James translation.

In the following verses you will find that the Angels are in Heaven and that all things in Heaven were created by God.

> Mark 12:25  For when they shall rise from the dead, they neither marry, nor are given in marriage; but are as ***the angels which are in heaven.***
>
> Mark 13:32  But of that day and that hour knoweth no man, no, not ***the angels which are in heaven,*** neither the Son, but the Father.
>
> Colossians 1:16 and 17  ***For by him were all things created, that are in heaven,*** and that are in earth, visible and invisible, whether they be thrones, or dominions, or principalities, or powers: all things were created by him, and for him: 17  And he is before all things, and by him all things consist.
>
> Revelation 4:11  Thou art worthy, O Lord, to receive glory and honour and power: for thou hast created all things, and **for thy pleasure they are and were created.**
>
> Revelation 10:6  And sware by him that liveth for ever and ever, ***who created heaven, and the things that therein are,*** and the earth, and the things that therein are, and the sea, and the things which are therein, that there should be time no longer:

So the Bible does say that the angels were created by God, and not only that but *they were created for his pleasure.* As was all else. Sometimes we have do some hearty research in order understand that God is omniscient, and also Omnipotent, and to find just where some answers to our questions are in the Bible.

Even though some answers are harder to discern than others I assure you they are all there, and that's where this site is such a boon to people. Christians have all learned different lessons through circumstance in life and it is that peculiar knowledge that we try to share on this site.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's curious to think of Lucifer pleasing God. It must have been a sad day when he rebelled.

Comment: @ShemSeger Lucifer in his created state did I'm sure please God, just as man did in his created state, and yes I'm quite sure All of Heaven was saddened at the rebellion of both.

Answer (score 0):

To attempt to answer this question, we need to look at the history of names and titles.

## Who is Lucifer?

First and foremost, the name Lucifer exists once in the the Bible and only in the King James Version.

**Isaiah 14:12 KJV**

> How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the morning! how
>   art thou cut down to the ground, which didst weaken the nations!

and in Hebrew:

> אֵיךְ נָפַלְתָּ מִשָּׁמַיִם, `הֵילֵל` בֶּן-שָׁחַר; נִגְדַּעְתָּ
>   לָאָרֶץ, חוֹלֵשׁ עַל-גּוֹיִם.

Looking at the [Hebrew version](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1014.htm) we find the word `הילל hêylêl` means "shining" or in the sense of brightness - which is usually associated with Seraphim (more about them later).  Furthermore the same word can be found in other translations of the bible and was referring to the morning star.  As seen in:

**Isaiah 14:12 NIV**

> How you have fallen from heaven,
>       morning star, son of the dawn! You have been cast down to the earth,
>       you who once laid low the nations!

It is quite popular to believe that Isaiah is talking about King of Babylon - Nebuchadnezzar and not Satan.

**From [Bible.Net](https://bible.org/netbible/index.htm?isa14.htm):**

> This whole section (vv. 4b-21) is directed to the king of Babylon, who
>   is clearly depicted as a human ruler. Other kings of the earth address
>   him in vv. 9ff., he is called "the man" in v. 16, and, according to
>   vv. 19-20, he possesses a physical body. Nevertheless the language of
>   vv. 12-15 has led some to see a dual referent in the taunt song. These
>   verses, which appear to be spoken by other pagan kings to a pagan king
>   (cf. vv. 9-11), contain several titles and motifs that resemble those
>   of Canaanite mythology, including references to Helel son of Shachar,
>   the stars of El, the mountain of assembly, the recesses of Zaphon, and
>   the divine title Most High. Apparently these verses allude to a
>   mythological story about a minor god (Helel son of Shachar) who tried
>   to take over Zaphon, the mountain of the gods. His attempted coup
>   failed and he was hurled down to the underworld. The king of Babylon
>   is taunted for having similar unrealized delusions of grandeur. Some
>   Christians have seen an allusion to the fall of Satan here, but this
>   seems contextually unwarranted.

However orthodox/mainstream Christianity has attributed the name Lucifer to Satan.

Therefore, I could stop here and say that Lucifer was created in the imagination of man who incorrectly associated the name to Satan.  The association is more than likely due to (or at least solidified by) [Paradise Lost](http://www.paradiselost.org/5-sum-short.html), an epic poem by the 17th-century English poet John Milton (1608–1674).  There is **NO Biblical** support for the association between Lucifer and Satan.

---

Digging into your question a bit, let's "assume" that you intended to ask, "How was Satan created?"

## Who is Satan?

Satan comes from Judaism; "Satan" is from the Hebrew word for "adversary." Satan was existed in the traditions of Judaism as the heavenly prosecutor in what Christians call the Old Testament long before the incarnation of the logos aka the birth of Jesus.

**Job 1:6 NIV**

> One day the angels came to present themselves before the Lord, and
>   Satan also came with them.

Satan's origins are hinted at here:

**Ezekiel 28:16 NIV**

> Through your widespread trade you were filled with violence, and you
>   sinned. So I drove you in disgrace from the mount of God, and I
>   expelled you, guardian cherub, from among the fiery stones.

Therefore, this begs the question... "When were the cherubim created?"  For further information regarding the hierarchy of angelic beings please read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_angelic_hierarchy).  And for FYI, "cherub" exists 26 times in the KJV of the Bible.  That's 26 more times than the name 'Lucifer" in the KJV.

## When were the cherubim created?

I do not know, the bible is not clear on this.  However it does suggest the power that they have in Isiah:

**Isaiah 37:16 NIV**

> Lord Almighty, the God of Israel, enthroned between the cherubim, you
>   alone are God over all the kingdoms of the earth. You have made heaven
>   and earth.

Here is a popular depiction of the order from Matthaeus (Matthäus) Merian the elder (1593-1650).
[image: Cherubim]

## Conclusion

While my answer may not directly give you the answer you're looking for.  I hope that with this bit of information I can help you frame your questions appropriately.  "How was Lucifer created?" is correctly asked as "How were the Cherubim created?"  Which may lead you to the answer that you're looking for.

I will do some more research and append to this answer, please check back...