# How do seraphim in Isaiah 6 relate to the cherubim?

Tags: biblical-basis, old-testament, isaiah

After reading [Isaiah chapter 6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=isaiah%206&version=NLT) I came across the spiritual beings named **seraphim**.

I have been introduced to other spiritual beings before, such as **cherubim**, a being that we have a variety of references.

However, the only reference that I saw of **seraphim** was in Isaiah chapter 6 and they are described to perform a role similar to the cherubim, with some variations, as they have 6 wings (instead of 2 or 4).

But I am struggling to understand **what are the seraphims and if they relate to cherubim**?

---

**Cherubim**

From **Genesis 3:24** we can see that **cherubim** are the guardians between heaven and earth.

> After sending them out, the Lord God stationed mighty cherubim to the east of the Garden of Eden. And he placed a flaming sword that flashed back and forth to guard the way to the tree of life.

From **Psalms 99:1** we read that they support Yahweh's throne:

> The Lord is king!
>       Let the nations tremble! He sits on his throne between the cherubim.
>       Let the whole earth quake!

From **Ezekiel 9:3**:

> Then the glory of the God of Israel rose up from between the cherubim,
>   where it had rested, and moved to the entrance of the Temple. And the
>   Lord called to the man dressed in linen who was carrying the writer’s
>   case.

And **Ezekiel 10:1**, that they carry his throne-chariot that appears to prophets on earth.

> In my vision I saw what appeared to be a throne of blue lapis lazuli
>   above the crystal surface over the heads of the cherubim.

---

I came across [this thread](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/35632/34561), however it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Cherubim are a concept. They are not persons. It is a mysterious and very spiritual concept which is like a thread running through many books of scripture. (Don't forget the man called _'Kerub'_ who went to Babylon . . .  and came back again.)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I have already given a link [The Cherubim of Glory](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxiZWxtb250cHVibGljYXRpb25zfGd4OjNlYWMyNDEyNWFiY2E4MzE) to Goncalo Peres but I was told TL;DR (too long; didn't read) because it is 60,000 words. I can't condense all that into a brief answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to The New Unger's Bible Dictionary, definition of **Cherub**

> They do not seem to be identical with the seraphim (Isa. 6:2). The cherubim apparently have to do with the holiness of God as
>   violated by sin; the seraphim with uncleanness in the people of God.